# Verificar se campo contém uma data

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma lista de um `EditText's` que são preenchidos com dados retornados do banco.

Alguns possui o um texto comum, por exemplo

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/edittext"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Jon Snow" />
```

E em outros casos pode ser uma data:

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/edittext"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="2017-06-20" />
```

Como poderia verificar se o texto que está sendo exibido no `EditText` é uma data ou um outro texto comum? Será que um *regex* resolveria isso?

Comment: Você precisa saber se é uma data no preenchimento do EditText (ao puxar os dados do banco de dados), ou em alguma outra hora?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isValidaData(String dataStr){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //Formate a data do jeito que for necessário, outro exemplo: ("dd/MM/yyyy")
    try {
        java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(dataStr).getTime());
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Depois é só chamar o método:

```
boolean dataValida = isValidaData(meuEditText.getText().toString());
```

Abraço!